# JavaScript: How to display alert box when value in text field is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a checkbox to the html page I am creating.

What I am trying to implement is: If value is changed in any textbox for "Post-IVR Call Volume" or "IVR Call Volume" AND if the value in any of text boxes in the same column below (the changed text box) are are different than the new value, then an alert box should be displayed.

For example, if "Post-IVR Call Volume" under Green is changed, then we should check vale in the text boxes under Green for all the hidden rows under "Post-IVR Call Volume". These hidden rows are: Alabama, Arkansas, Arizona.

The alert box I'll use will be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=window.confirm("You have set a unique threshold for one or more states below. Are you sure you want to reset them all?")
if (x)
    window.alert("Thresholds changed!(Form submitted)")
else
    window.alert("Thresholds not changed!(Form NOT submitted)")
</script>
```

But I am not able to figure out how to implement the logic in javascript for the check to detect change in text field (after submit button is clicked). The html code I am using is given below and the jsfiddle link is: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/0u5yzgu6/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $(".expand1").toggle();
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    $(".expand2").toggle();
  });
})
```

```css
<style> .expand1 {
  display: none;
}
.expand2 {
  display: none;
}
body {
  background-color: AliceBlue;
}
span.note1 {
  float: left
}
span.note2 {
  font-size: 80%
}
table#t02,
#t02 th,
#t02 td {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 80%;
}
#button1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div style="float:left; width:50%">

    <table id="t02" class="table2">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th style="color:green">Green</th>
        <th style="color:gold" , colspan="3">Yellow</th>
        <th></th>
        <th style="color:red">Red</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="btn1">Post-IVR Call Volume</td>
        <td>&lt</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_good_high" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_low" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>to</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_high" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>&gt</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_critical_low" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Alabama</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_good_high_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_low_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_high_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_critical_low_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Arkansas</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_good_high_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_low_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_high_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_critical_low_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Arizona</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_good_high_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_low_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_warning_high_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="post_ivr_call_volume_critical_low_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="btn2">IVR Call Volume</td>
        <td>&lt</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_good_high" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_low" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>to</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_high" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>&gt</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_critical_low" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Alabama</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_good_high_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_low_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_high_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_critical_low_alabama" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Arkansas</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_good_high_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_low_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_high_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_critical_low_arkansas" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Arizona</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_good_high_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_low_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_warning_high_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="ivr_call_volume_critical_low_arizona" , size="2" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Note: html when I try from browser does expand and collapse when I click on "Post-IVR Call Volume" or "IVR Call Volume" but somehow from jsfiddle it doesn't work.

Can I get some help or direction on how to implement the check when text field is changed.

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery in the fiddle.

Comment: To fix your JSFiddle issue - select jQuery 2.1.3 on top left corner. Its because jquery library is not loaded

Comment: Didn't you notice the error about `$` not being defined in the Javascript console? If you didn't check the console, why not, isn't that the first place you look when Javascript isn't working?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, afrin. This was my first attempt using jsfiddle. I found the option to select jquery. And I am sorry but I still can't find the error about $ not being defined in javascript console.

Comment: @300 Whilst information is often key, too much information will put people off answering your question. Try to narrow down your problem to a few lines of code in future.

Comment: @rybo111 Thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely remember it and will try to narrow down the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've kept this short and sweet so you can see what's happening.

HTML:

```
<form class="my-form">
    <input type="text" class="my-input">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('input', '.my-input', function(){
    $(this).closest('form').addClass('changed');
});

$(document).on('submit', '.my-form', function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('changed')){
        alert('submitted and changed');
    } else{
        alert('submitted and NOT changed');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This adds a class to your form, so it can check for the change on submit.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/refg2ow7/)

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the `changed` class value after alert has been shown? Otherwise everytime you hit submit its gonna keep showing alerts due to the set value.

(If its for demo purposes to the OP, then ignore!! )

Comment: @afrin216 Assuming that is the desired effect, then yes. If so: `$(this).removeClass('changed');` would go before `e.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Thank you afrin216, I am trying your suggestion and will update here soon. Also, I'll add $(this).removeClass('changed'); above e.preventDefault(); and below the closing }.

Comment: Thanks again rybo111 and @afrin216. Needless to say your suggestion works great for me. I just changed it a little as I want to allow form submission only if user confirms s/he wants to make the change. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/refg2ow7/1/) 
Along with window.alert what I should add so the form is not submitted if user clicks cancel on window.confirm and the form is submitted if user clicks ok on window.confirm?

Comment: UPDATE:I am using <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submitButton\" value=\"Submit\" id=\"button1\" />

Comment: @300 If you have further questions, please ask a new question, and limit to a few lines of code where possible.